# How to catch DB exceptions in Zend's (1.11) ErrorController?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm currently working on a project based on Zend 1.11 where I'm required to catch database related exceptions and display a notification should one occur. Needless to say I'm completely new to Zend Framework...

Judging by what I see in the default action defined within the ErrorController, I don't have a clue on how to achieve this:

```
class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    private $logPriority_;

    public function errorAction()
    {
        $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        if (!$errors || !$errors instanceof ArrayObject)
            $this->_forward('notfound','error');

        switch ($errors->type) {
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
                // 404 error -- controller or action not found
                $this->_forward('notfound','error');
                break;
            default:
                // application error
                break;
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
        $this->view->message = '500 Internal Server Error';
        $this->logErrors(Zend_Log::CRIT);
    }
    // ...
```

Where and how should I approach this issue?

Comment: The purpose of the error controller is to catch exceptions and show a user friendly error message by default - when you say you want the app to 'display a notification', how is this different from what is currently happening?

Comment: Well, what I need specifically is to determine (within the error controller) that the exception that was thrown was related to accessing the database, in which case I should display a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if Zend_Db_Exception is thrown:

```
if($errors->exception and $errors->exception instanceof Zend_Db_Exception) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I've made a modification to this and apparently, that's a good solution:  `if ($errors->exception and $errors->exception instanceof Model_Database_DatabaseException) {}`